# npm search private registry

Tags: node.js, npm

i am able to interact with my private (organization) npm registry

```sh
$ npm whoami --scope @myorg
my-org-name

$ npm view @myorg/pkg-name _npmUser
my-org-name <admin@my-org-name.com>
```

but i am unable to search the private npm registry.

note that the organization npm registry does not have a dedicated hostname

```sh
$ cat ~/.npmrc
@myorg:registry=https://registry.npmjs.org/
//registry.npmjs.org/:_authToken=xxxx-xxxx
```

how can i search within a private npm registry using the command line, that is via `npm search`?